# In react, how can I deselect an element after it has been set as active with onClick?

Tags: reactjs

I have an image grid in react, with an onclick function that highlights the selected image. Clicking another image will change the active element but I'd like to be able to re-click the selected icon to deselect it and return the grid to default.

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/team-grid-slicer-forked-9004g?file=/src/App.js:0-1176) and the script is below

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Data } from "./Data.js";
function App() {
  const scrollRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = scrollRef.current;
    if (el) {
      const wheelListener = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        el.scrollTo({
          left: el.scrollLeft + e.deltaY * 5,
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
      };
      el.addEventListener("wheel", wheelListener);
      return () => el.removeEventListener("wheel", wheelListener);
    }
  }, []);

  const [active, setActive] = useState(-1);
  const [active2, setActive2] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div ref={scrollRef} className="grid_container">
      {Data.map((prev, i) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setActive(i);
              setActive2(true);
              console.log(prev.Team);
            }}
            className={`${
              (active === i && "scale") || (active2 && "notScale")
            } card`}
            key={i}
          >
            <img src={prev.TeamBadge} alt="" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I think this solves the problem, based on the codesandbox:

```
        onClick={() => {
          setActive(i);
          if (active === i) {
            setActive2(null);
            setActive(null);
          } else {
            setActive2(true);
          }
          console.log(i);
          console.log(prev.Team);
        }}
```

since every team has its unique number, the logic here is to check if the same number is in the state (if that makes sense). Let me know if this was you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks - this does the first bit great.  Allows me to select another team or re-click the active team to deselect.  However,  once I have deselected the active team it then doesn't allow me to reselect it - if that makes sense?   Maybe there needs to be an extra step in the logic to allow the previously deselected item to be reselected?

Comment: I edited my response, can you re-test it?

Comment: Perfect - Thanks so much for taking the time to help, much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can set your state like that :

```
  setActive2(!active2);
```